# SQL Summary Sum Table inefficient due to needing to show zeroes - is there a better way? MSACCESS/SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I use this VBA code to populate the RowSource of a data table in MSAccess with data obtained from a SQL query in the database.

This particular query should be relatively simple and efficient. It essentially needs to add up all the points for a username, between two dates and show the total next to their name. The problem that is making this complex, is the need to show zeroes.

As it stands the code looks like this:

```
        .subProdSheet_table.Form.RecordSource = " SELECT adj.TM_StaffName AS Staff_Name, Nz(Sum(ps.PS_Points+ps.PS_AdhocPts),0) AS [Total Points] " & _
                                                " FROM [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=<REDACTED>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=<REDACTED>].dbo.SD_StaffMembers as adj " & _
                                                " LEFT JOIN [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=<REDACTED>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=<REDACTED>].dbo.PS_DB as ps ON (((cstr(adj.TM_StaffMember) = cstr(ps.PS_StaffMember)) AND cdate(ps.PS_Date) >= #" & getNextWeek_Start & "#) AND cdate(ps.PS_Date) <= #" & getNextWeek_End & "#) " & _
                                                " WHERE adj.TM_TeamName = '" & tmName & "' " & _
                                                " GROUP BY adj.TM_StaffMember; "
```

This populates a table that looks like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+
| Staff Member | Total Points |
+--------------+--------------+
| John A       |        11.25 |
| John B       |         7.75 |
| John C       |           14 |
| John D       |           13 |
| John E       |        14.25 |
| John F       |           14 |
| John G       |         5.75 |
| John H       |            6 |
| John J       |         10.5 |
| John K       |            2 |
| John L       |            0 |
| John M       |         9.75 |
+--------------+--------------+
```

The key part is that it shows John L as a zero. I could write a far less complex version of this that would use one table to sum them directly and the performance would be great; would calculate near instant. But in order to have the complete list of staff (and their total as zero if they haven't entered data), I have to write it this way.

Is there a more efficient way to write the query? Or is it the way I am linking to the SQLServer database?
Is there a better way to return this data into the rowsource in a more efficient way?

Comment: The problem isn't zeroes, it's the `CSTR` and `CDATE` calls. Those aren't T-SQL functions. Second, `CDATE` wouldn't be needed if the fields used a date-related type, preferably `date`. I suspect what you wrote loads everything into access and tries to join the tables there instead of using SQL Server and its indexes to run the query. I suspect if you clean up the query and run it in SSMS you won't notice any performance issues

Comment: You also really need to look into using parameterized queries. This code is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos that did indeed speed things up somewhat. I'd prefer to use a pass-through query as when this ran in SSMS it was instant as you said. But I'm not sure how you'd apply a pass-through query into a RecordSource which is I think, what is causing me the issue here.